# Clojure - update hashmaps inside vectors

Tags: clojure, hashmap

Let's suppose I have the following vector

```
[{:id "1" :type "type"}, {:id "2" :type "another-type"}]
```

And I want to write a function that updates a hashmap, depending on it's id.

```
(defn update
  [vector id value]
  ....)
```

And the result would be:

```
(update vector "1" "value")

[{:id "1" :type "type" :new-key ["value"]}, {:id "2" :type "another-type"}]
```

What's the most idiomatic way of performing this change?

Comment: This is going to be O(n). If you really need to do this, I'd consider setting up your data differently, unless performance isn't a concern at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(mapv 
  (fn [m]
    (if (= "1" (:id m)) (assoc m :new-key ["value"]) m))
  vector)
```

Comment: mapv is supposed to return a vector, right? In that case, it returns a vector of vectors, not a vector of hashmaps as I expect.

Comment: @madam - If `vector` is the collection in your question, the result will be another vector of maps.

Comment: that's right! thanks :)